# How do I get IIS6 to default new websites to ASP.NET version 2 instead of version 1?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net

Whenever I create a new website on our W2K3 box, the ASP.NET tab defaults to version 1.1.4322. Changing it by hand results in IIS restarting. I'd like to have the tab default to ASP.NET version 2.0.50727 when creating a new website (hoping to avoid the IIS restart).

Comment: Do you need that version selectable on your webserver?  I believe if you simply disable it, IIS6 should default to version 2.

Comment: No, I don't think so. However, I have another W2K3 server that works the way I want it to (with both versions enabled), but I don't know how it got into that state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was answered on SO.

[How DoYou Tell IIS 6 to set the net version to 2.0 not 1.1 when new sites are created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279/how-do-you-tell-iis-6-to-set-the-net-version-to-2-0-not-1-1-when-new-sites-are)